# Prevent execution of a specific inline script tag

Tags: javascript, html, tampermonkey

I'm trying to write a script for [Tampermonkey](http://tampermonkey.net/) that prevents the execution of a specific inline script tag. The body of the page looks something like this

```
<body>
  <!-- the following script tag should be executed-->
  <script type="text/javascript">
    alert("I'm executed as normal")
  </script>
  <!-- the following script tag should NOT be executed-->
  <script type="text/javascript">
    alert("I should not be executed")
  </script>
  <!-- the following script tag should be executed-->
  <script type="text/javascript">
    alert("I'm executed as normal, too")
  </script>
</body>
```

I tried to remove the `script` tag using my Tampermonkey script, but if I [run it at](http://tampermonkey.net/documentation.php?ext=dhdg#_run_at) `document-start` or `document-body` the `script` tag does not exist yet. If I run it at `document-end` or `document-idle` the `script` tag I'd like to remove is run before my Tampermonkey script is executed.

How can I prevent execution of the `script` tag?

---

**Note:** The actual `script` tag that I'd like to prevent from executing contains `window.location = 'redirect-url'`. So it would also be sufficient to prevent the reload in this case.

---

Versions:

- Chromium 65.0.3325.181
- Tampermonkey 4.5

Comment: In Chrome there's no way to *prevent* it, but you can stop loading, fetch and rewrite html of the page ([example](https://greasyfork.org/en/scripts/14164-kinozal-tv-remove-external-scripts/code)).

Comment: Thanks, that helped me to figure out a [similar solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50024143/1065654).

Comment: Another possible solution is to attach a mutation observer to `document.documentElement` on `document_start`, and remove the script once it's been added. That worked for me in Chome 85.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternative version free of doc.write/XHR --

```
   (() => { 
          'use strict';
          let needle = '/window.location/';
          if ( needle === '' || needle === '{{1}}' ) {
              needle = '.?';
          } else if ( needle.slice(0,1) === '/' && needle.slice(-1) === '/' ) {
              needle = needle.slice(1,-1);
          } else {
              needle = needle.replace(/[.*+?^${}()|[\]\\]/g, '\\$&');
          }
          needle = new RegExp(needle);
          const jsnode = () => {
                        try {
                            const jss = document.querySelectorAll('script');
                            for (const js of jss) {
                                if (js.outerHTML.match(needle)) {
                                        js.remove();
                                }           
                            }
                        } catch { }
          };
          const observer = new MutationObserver(jsnode);
          observer.observe(document.documentElement, { childList: true, subtree: true });
})();
```

Comment: The script is still executed before it is removed if I run your script at `document-start`.

Comment: Unfortunate race condition on browser side, nothing I can do about it :( The one posted by you also suffers from race condition but it's thwarted by window.stop() upto some extent depending on different pages.

Comment: Modified verison using MutationObserver, try that and let me know if it works for you.

Comment: No, it does not prevent the removed script from running. `jsnode` is run after the script has been executed.

Comment: post the url where it doesn't work, so I can reproduce it myself. Also does this happen on Firefox or on Chrome ?

Comment: Chrome. Just use the snippet from the question to test on localhost. Did you test your solution anywhere, where it does work?

Comment: Sure, I wouldn't post if it didn't work in the first place. For example, sportingnews.com, They have ads inserted via Instart Logic, so replace /window.location/ with /INSTART/ and browse to that website, no Instart g00 crap will get loaded, not even their domains will make network requests if you check via devtools. You tested on localhost, I can't do that as I only run my router there and nothing else. I suggest you test on the suggested website instead. Also make sure you're inserting the snippet at document-start.

Comment: Your solution works for script tags that are added to the DOM by a script, but it does not work on script tags that are part of the `index.html`. By the way, the website, where I wanted to remove the script tag, does not exist anymore, but it had the script tag in the `body` of the `index.html`.

Comment: I would appreciate if you post the URL of that website here or any other website with index.html, so I can see for myself.

Comment: Since the original website does not exist anymore, I created a website to test for you https://prevent-execution-of-a-specific-inline-script-tag.surge.sh that redirects to this question. Try to prevent the redirect.

Comment: Race condition. No js snippet would work there, including the one posted by woXXom. For that one, you will need CSP to abort execution.

Answer (score 6):

Delete script tag on `document-start` (as suggested by [wOxxOm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50020880/prevent-execution-of-a-specific-inline-script-tag?noredirect=1#comment87058346_50020880)):

```
(function() {
    'use strict';
    window.stop();
    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET', window.location.href);
    xhr.onload = () => {
        var html = xhr.responseText
        .replace(/<script\b[\s\S]*?<\/script>/g, s => {
            // check if script tag should be replaced/deleted
            if (s.includes('window.location')) {
                return '';
            } else {
                return s;
            }
        });
        document.open();
        document.write(html);
        document.close();
    };
    xhr.send();
})();
```

Comment: I used your code and it works perfectly except that favicons are not displayed in my Vivaldi browser. Do you have any idea what is the cause of this behavior? I asked a question on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65103986/favicon-disappears-after-preventing-execution-of-a-specific-inline-script-tag-by

Comment: @azerbajdzan I see you have found an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65105618/1065654) to your question