# chrome extension onUpdated fired too late

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Good morning
I try with a chrome extension or userscript to remove a script before he is executed.
I have tried

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabid, info, tab) {
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabid, {file:"test.js"});
    //if (info.status == "complete") {
      //
   // }
});
```

And in test.js I remove the script element who is the first (just for the example)

```
document.body.querySelectorAll('*')[0].remove()
```

Even the first call of test.js is too late the script inside the page has already been executed.
Is there a way to replace HTML before interpretation or remove script before execution?

I also tried `"run_at": "document_start"` for userscript but the script is run before the script I want to remove is loaded in the dom so I can't remove it.
In the past, it was possible with the beforeload event but it has been removed from chrome.
I also tried `chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener` and `chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener` but they are not fired when I reload the page.
Thank you

Comment: That won't help. You'll have to rewrite the entire page html, [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50020880). And you'll need to use runAt: 'document_start' in executeScript of course.

Comment: Thanks you. The problem with this method is that the request is made twice but if I can block the first request first it is the solution.

Comment: In Chrome this is the only method, unfortunately.

Comment: window.stop() is not sufficient I have replaced it by document.close();window.stop();  it is working even if we lost a little time.

Answer (score 0):

Finally instead of an extension, I use mitmproxy which is a proxy that allows to modify content.

Installation of mitmproxy:

```
sudo apt install pip
pip3 install beautifulsoup4
#pip3 uninstall mitmproxy #uncomment if already installed
sudo pip3 install mitmproxy==3.0.4

sudo sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1 #maybe facultative
```

Create a python modifier script named insertJs.py:
The following script will replace `$('html, body').animate({".encode('utf-8')` by `;[].push({".encode('utf-8')` on site that contains `tfarjo`

```
def response(flow):
    if 'tfarjo' in flow.request.url: #here filter url that you want modify
        #here make the replacement you want
        flow.response.content = flow.response.content.replace(
            "$('html, body').animate({".encode('utf-8'),
            ";[].push({".encode('utf-8')
        )

def read_file(filename):
    with open(filename) as f:
        return f.read()
```

Launch mitmproxy with a modifier script :

```
sudo mitmdump -p 8081 -s "insertJs.py"
```

kill chrome: file -> quit or "`killall chrome`" twice

Now we have to configure the proxy, create a chrome shorcut that add the mitmproxy (on linux mint it is right clic on desktop and create new launcher):

```
/usr/bin/google-chrome-stable %U --proxy-server=127.0.0.1:8081
```

try on an http page not an https, then if it works then configure https:

For chrome
do the same and install pem ( probably facultative )
then follow these instruction https://superuser.com/questions/1083766/how-do-i-deal-with-neterr-cert-authority-invalid-in-chrome#answer-1083768

(For firefox it is simpler just click on your os and https is configured)